# Referencing a GridView which is located within a modal window - (C#)

Tags: c#, gridview, bootstrap-modal

I have a GridView (gvSummary) which contains a button on each row. When this button is clicked, it opens up a modal window displaying a second GridView (gvDetail). From the source code, I can not seem to reference this second GridView. When I do try it gives the error message `"The name gvDetail does not exist in the current context."`

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btn_open" runat="server" OnClick="btn_open_Click" Text="Show Gridview" CssClass="openModal" CommandName="cmdDetail"/>
                <div class="modal" id="idModal">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1>Transaction Details<a class="close-modal" href="#">&times;</a></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvDetail" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlgvDetail" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                            OnRowDataBound="gvDetail_RowDataBound" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered" EmptyDataText="No data to display." >
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="metalid" HeaderText="Metal ID"/>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="enddate" HeaderText="End Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="startdate" HeaderText="Start Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="clientref" HeaderText="Client Ref" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_close" runat="server" Text="OK" CssClass="close-modal btn-sm btn-primary"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-backdrop"></div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The above TemplateField is located within the first Gridview.
Is there a way I can reference this GridView from the source code?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying get the reference of child gridview `gvDetail`? If so, I think this what you can do. You should be able to find `gvDetail` via its parent gridview's `OnROwDataBound` event.

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // get the reference of child gridview
        GridView gvDetail = e.Row.FindControl("gvDetail") as GridView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, spot on. Cheers @woodykiddy